# Getting a section of an array in OpenCL

Tags: arrays, opencl

I need to test if an array except for one index contains a specific number. I can't think of a great way to explain this, so I'm just going to write the python equivalent.

```
ommited_index = 2 #The index I want to omit
element_to_search_for = 2 #The element I'm searching for
array = [0,1,2,3,4] #A basic array, the original
new_array = array[:ommited_index]+array[ommited_index+1:] #Taking the ommited index out of the array via slicing
output = element_to_search_for in new_array #Checking if the element is in the array
print (output)
```

What can I do to copy this behavior in an OpenCL kernel?

This is also similar to a yellow letter in Wordle, which is actually the behavior I am trying to test for here.

Comment: Just use an if check before the comparison for the wanted element. Check if index is not equal to the ommited index. Then atomically write the index value that points to the wanted number, to an output address. This works if you have only 1 gpu and if numbers are unique. If numbers are not unique then you will need to also atomically increment the output address to have an output array.